# Why is the magnitude of the electric field dependent only on $x$ and $y$ coordinates?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, maxwell-equations, waveguide

So I am reading a book on electromagnetism and in it they are assuming that the magnitude of the electric field is dependent only on $x$ and $y$ coordinates in a waveguide and I wanted to know why this assumption was made?

[image: wave equations]

Answer (score -1):

The "t" and "z" dependence is assumed to be $\mathbf{E}(x,y,z,t)=\mathbf{\hat {E}}(x,y) e^{\mathfrak{j}(\omega t - kz)}$, when you substitute this into Maxwell's equations you can divide both sides with the exponential, note that $c = \omega/k $

Comment: But why can't the equation be $$\mathbf{E}(x,y,z,t)=\mathbf{\hat {E}}(x,y,z) e^{\mathfrak{j}(\omega t - kz)}$$

Comment: because the wave-guide has translational symmetry w.r.t $z$: there is no preferred $z$ for a frequency component to have $z$ dependence.

Comment: @cojoye because we are looking for solutions of that form. We are looking for transverse waves (because they are sustainable for longer distances).

Comment: It can be but you want to find the simplest set of solutions of your problem from which all the *others* can be built up as a linear sum. Think of a Fourier series of a periodic function $f(t)=\Sigma_k A_k e^{\mathfrak{j} k\Omega t}$, if the coeffs are still dependent on $t$, $A_k=A_k(t)$,  then the series expansion is not very useful. This has nothing to do with being transverse or longitudinal waves, rather that the waveguide is homogeneous in "z" hence we expect that such solutions might exist.